# How to remove view from window?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, subview

I am using Cocos2D for my main framework.  In some cases, I want Cocos2D to load a nib file and have that be the view:

```
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
TargetPlayerViewController *myController = [[TargetPlayerViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TargetPlayerViewController" bundle:nil];
[window addSubview:[myController view]];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

This works as expected, and shows the `TargetPlayerViewController`. Wonderful!

What I need to know is: once that view has been loaded, how can I have the view remove itself?  I've tried a few different ways, but all of them result in the program crashing.

To test I have a button on the view set up which triggers this method:

```
- (IBAction)GTFOnow:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"GFTO");
    //window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    //[self.view removeFromSuperview];
    //[window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

GTFOnow is a method in TargetPlayerViewController.  When it is called, the current subview (that was called in the Cocos2D code above) should be removed from the window.

Comment: "In this method the view should remove itself from the view". This is very confusing. I suppose you mean the view controller should remove the view from the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't create a new window just because you want to remove a subview. Secondly, whatever else happens, this shouldn't cause the app to crash. In which class do you have the `GTFOnow`method? I suppose in the `TargetPlayerViewController` class?

Comment: The GTFOnow method is in the TargetPlayerViewController. I was hoping the view could remove itself from the window.

Comment: Yes the view can be removed from the window (although it's the controller that is removing it, so it's not really removing "itself"). But you don't need to create a new window as you do in this code. Instead you need to get a reference to the window that was created at startup, in your app delegate. That's the window the view is a child of, and that's the one you want to remove it from. In general, you very rarely want to create a second window in an iPhone app.